# How to authenticate with multiple identity providers using ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have a ASP.NET CORE 3.1 application with an authentication module connected to an Azure Active Directory Tenant, and in want to add a second authentication against a B2C Tenant.

Do you think it is possible to have two way for connect a user in the application ?

Comment: Why would you like to enable both Azure AD authentication and a B2C authentication.? If you use Azure AD B2C authentication you can add Azure AD as an Idp and use Local Idp(B2C tenant).

Comment: Thank you for your response, i need to use AD authentication for give an access of the tenant's MS Graph, and B2C can't give an access to it because it is an other tenant.

Comment: Use [AAD federation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga) and [IdP token pass through](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/idp-pass-through-custom). You can do it with User Flows too. This way your app only expects back a B2C token. And the token can have the AAD token from the federated IdP embedded inside it as a claim.

Comment: i have configure my user flow to authenticate with my AAD (AAD app with MsGraph authorizations), but i don't understand how can i request MsGraph with a token. Do you have any resources for this ?

Comment: See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user and Postman sample here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman.